# How to create script with Drush commands?

Tags: drupal, drush

Is it possible to create file with sequence of drush commands to be executed? 
In particular, I would like to write script, that would download and enable more Drupal modules for example script with these lines (pseudocode).

```
$modules = {"pathauto", "admin_menu", "i18n"}
drush dl $modules;
drush en $modules;
```

Is it possible without creating custom drush command?

Answer (score 0):

I have already found solution. I can create a script with Drush API and using [drush_invoke](http://api.drush.ws/api/drush/includes!command.inc/function/drush_invoke/5.x) command I can call another drush commands.